# sql server 2008 security what is owner

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been working with SQL SERVER for years without thinking of what is dbo, a shame. Recently I have been studying security of SQL Server 2008. I have been overwhelmed by lots of concepts. So please clarify me first on these concepts (correct me if I am wrong). I don't need a thorough explanation on everything, just an idea what does what and their relationship to each other.

LOGIN: server level (sql server login or windows login).

USER: database level. (a user is mapped to a login).

ROLE: USERS belong to a ROLE. Can be a server level or a database level with permissions attached.

SCHEMA: database objects belong to a SCHEMA (or dbo by default)

PERMISSION: for database objects or schema. A USER or a ROLE has permissions for a object or SCHEMA.

OWNER: owner of object or SCHEMA? what does it do? How it works? Where I can see the owner of a object in SSMS? I see only SCHEMA.object.

Thanks,
Nian

Comment: Believe me I have read it a lot. Just need some clarification. And if this is the answer then no one need to go to some forum and ask a question.

Comment: I'm sorry - you're right - up to the point of "owner", the docs are pretty good. But on the question of ownership, it seems the MSDN docs and the reality in SSMS don't quite match...

Comment: You should ask this on dba.stackexchange.com - that's where the real SQL Server DBA gurus hang out - they might know exactly how this all works in detail

Comment: Thanks marc, a lot of articles out there but seems I couldn't find one with a higher level outline about how all these concepts work together. That link seems nice, I have asked the same question there (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30396/sql-server-2008-security-what-is-owner). Thanks.